# FileNotFoundException when calling remote C# dll from C++/CLR

Tags: c#, .net

My project is a plug in for a platform which is built in Native C++. And the plugin will reuse the current functionalities of an existing C# project, which is built upon .NET framework 4.0. We use the C++/CLR as the bridge to call C# codes. That is, the host application, built in unmanaged c++, calls into managed C++ dll which calls into C# dll.

The platform will run in one process and the plugin will run in another process.
And the way for the platform to find the plugin dll is that user will input a directory in the platform's user interface, thus the platform the load all plugin dlls in that directory into the plugin process.

This works well when my plugin folder is a local folder. However, when I set the plugin folder as the remote folder, and when I tried to instantiate a C# class from C++/CLR class, I got a FileNotFoundException, the detailed information is "Unknown URL protocol".

Our plugin project has both C++/CLR and C# codes, built into different dll files. In Debug mode, in the Visual Studio Modules view, it turns out that C++/CLR dlls are loaded while C# dll not loaded(both are in the app directory). And the exception happens when I tried to instantiate a managed class in C++/CLR codes, however, unfortunately there’s no stack call when I got the exception.

So how can I allow the host plugin process to load the remote C# dll properly?

Comment: Try enabling [loadFromRemoteSources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409252(v=vs.110).aspx) in your C++/CLI application manifest.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried in the C++/CLI application, but does't succeed. Is there any other hints?

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, we found the root cause is that the plugin's ApplicationBase is not set correctly. For some reason, if the folder is set as a remote folder, the platform passes the folder in Linux format rather than windows format, and our software is running on Windows only. This is why "FileNotFoundException" is thrown and it works well when my plugin folder is a local folder. We need to correct the ApplicationBase in windows path format.